# UPDATE multiple rows in a MySQL table based on id existence in another table

Tags: mysql

I would normally do this programmatically, but I'm in a learning mood today... I looked around SO but didn't find anything exactly like my problem.

I have two tables `item`, `person`, and a third that contains associations, `item_person`. Not everyone has an item so the association doesn't always exist. Now, I want to maintain a `status` column in the `item` table which is partly based on whether an item is associated with a person. So...

```
Table: item
    item_id
    description
    status

Table: person
    person_id
    name

Table: item_person
    item_id
    person_id
```

Imagines that I want to `UPDATE` the item status to `1` if an association exists in `item_person`...

- Is there a single MySQL query that can handle this?
- Is there a single MySQL query that can do an `UPDATE` if an association **doesn't** exist in `item_person`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- If the association exists...
update item i
join item_person ip
    on ip.item_id = i.item_id
set i.status = 1

-- If the association does not exist...
update item i
left join item_person ip
    on ip.item_id = i.item_id
set i.status = 0
where ip.item_id is null
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm so out of practice that I forgot that a JOIN would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. UPDATE item set item_status = 1 where exists item_person.item = item.item_id
2. UPDATE item set item_status = 1 where not exists item_person.item = item.item_id

Note, both queries are untested, as I don't have access to mysql from here and you haven't given a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Feel free to leave a comment if you need help debugging though.